# Not Receiving Pending Message in JMS

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic, spring-jms

I am working with ActiveMQ and JMS

I have created a ObjectMessage in queue. I am not able to recieve it.

Take a look at message already available at Queue.
[image: Object Queue]

My code for Receiving message is

```
public class RecieveObjectQueue {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");


        try {
            ConnectionFactory connFactory=(ConnectionFactory) ctx.getBean("connectionFactory");

            Connection connection=connFactory.createConnection();
            connection.start();

        Session session=connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        Queue queue = new ActiveMQQueue(SendObjectQueue.OBJECT_QUEUE);

        MessageConsumer messageConsumer=session.createConsumer(queue);
        //          messageConsumer.receive();

        messageConsumer.setMessageListener(new MessageListener() {

            @Override
            public void onMessage(Message message) {
                ActiveMQObjectMessage activeMsg=(ActiveMQObjectMessage) message;
                /*if(message instanceof Car){
                    Car car=(Car) message;
                    System.out.println("Recieved Car=>"+car);
                }else{
                    System.out.println("Message is not a car object!!!");
                }*/

            }
        });
        } catch (JMSException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

If any more clarity or code is required, Please ask for it.

Answer (score 0):

You are consuming (and discarding) the message with this code...

```
messageConsumer.receive();
```

Comment: Even without receive, I don't receive any messages